# Como habilito funciones javascript en github-pages?

Tags: javascript, github-pages

> Hola! Tengo una web como portafolio la cual tengo subida a github
> pages, la web funciona impecable no tiene problemas excepto por un
> detalle, en mi copia alojada en mi computadora funciona todo
> incluyendo lo que mas me acompleja que es que tengo una funcion en js
> que mide distancias entre el menu y el top de la pagina para mantener
> su posicion y esta baje al hacer scroll.
>
> Todo bien hasta ahi, pero al momento de subirla a github pages, a pesar
> que la pagina se ve claramente las funciones js no funcionan.
>
> dejo el codigo de la funcion y del link de mi github pages
>
> Link codigo de mi portafolio:

https://github.com/K3yr0nym0us/K3yr0nym0us.github.io

> Tambien dejo el link de mi pagina visible en github pages

https://k3yr0nym0us.github.io/Index.html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*creamos una variable llamada altura que contendra
    el valor en pixeles de la diferencia que hay entre
    el objeto de clase menu y el top de la pantalla*/
    var altura = $('.menu').offset().top;

    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        /*si el scroll del sitio es mayor a altura*/
        if ( $(window).scrollTop() > altura ){
            /*entonces se añade la clase menu-fixed*/
            $('.menu').addClass('menu-fixed');
        } else {
            /*sino se remueve la clase*/
            $('.menu').removeClass('menu-fixed');
        }
    })
});
```

> Cabe destacar que la subi el codigo exactamente como funciona en mi computadora y
> en ella funciona pero en github pages no.
> Dejo el codigo de mi head donde tengo la llamada de mi js.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Portafolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pie.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
```

> cualquier consejo o critica es aceptada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si miras la consola de DevTools verás que el problema que estás teniendo es que el navegador se niega a cargar la librería jQuery porque estás usando una URL insegura: `http://` en lugar de `https://`. Una vez que arregles ese problema jQuery cargará y el resto de tu javascript podrá usarlo sin problema.

Comment: exelente amigo era solo agregar la s al final de la llamada del script en el html <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>